# BASH - file test within a variable

Tags: bash

I'm trying to find out whether a file is an image or not and then do something according to the result.This works fine for file in the present working directory and in other directories:

```
file -ib "$i" | grep "image/"
```

But this only works with files in the present directory (where the script was called from)

```
TEST=$(file -ib "$i" | grep "image/")

if [ "$TEST" == "" ]
then
    echo "Image"
else
    echo "Not an image"
fi
```

So something like ../../my.jpg works in the first case, but always gives "Not an image" in the second case. I would like to use my script on files anywhere on the system.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What does `bash -x second-fragment.sh` show as the value in `$TEST`?  That'll tell you what you need to do to fix the problem.

Comment: I assume you are setting `i=$1` or similar in the script case?

Comment: You seem to have your condition wrong. TEST will be empty if grep doesn't find image.

Comment: Do you need the value of `TEST` later?  If not you can do the command directly in the `if`

Comment: Let me try to explain a little better:

Comment: `file -ib my.jpg | grep "image/"`gives: image/jpeg; charset=binary. `file -ib ../../my.jpg | grep "image/"`gives: image/jpeg; charset=binary. Echoing $TEST for `TEST=$(file -ib my.jpg | grep "image/")` gives: image/jpeg; charset=binary. Echoing $TEST for `TEST=$(file -ib ../../my.jpg | grep "image/")` gives a blank line. The problem seems to be the ../../ when it is used inside $(...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
path="path/to/images/folder"
for i in $(find $path -type f); do
  file -ib "$i" | grep -q "image/" && echo "$i: Image" || echo "$i: Not an image";
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
TEST=$(file -i "$i" | grep ': *image/')

if [ "$TEST" = "" ];then 
  echo "not an image"
else 
  echo "it is an image"
fi
```